# I get android studio layout and grade error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-application

After downloading the mobile application I downloaded from Github, I get such errors, what is the solution for all of them?

[image]

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Android Studio as administrator

Windows :

Right click on launcher icon of Android Studio then click on "Run as administrator"

Comment: it really worked thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help you